# After Changing Python Version 3.6 to 3.10 I got cannot import name 'Callable' from 'collections'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, celery, celery-task

```
 File "C:\Users\Codertjay\PycharmProjects\Teems_App_Kid\teems_app_kid\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app   File "C:\Users\Codertjay\PycharmProjects\Teems_App_Kid\teems_app_kid\celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery   File "C:\Users\Codertjay\PycharmProjects\brownie\Teems_App_Kid\lib\site-packages\celery\five.py", line 306, in __getattr__
    module = __import__(self._object_origins[name], None, None, [name])   File "C:\Users\Codertjay\PycharmProjects\brownie\Teems_App_Kid\lib\site-packages\celery\app\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from celery import _state   File "C:\Users\Codertjay\PycharmProjects\brownie\Teems_App_Kid\lib\site-packages\celery\_state.py", line 20, in <module>
    from celery.utils.threads import LocalStack   File "C:\Users\Codertjay\PycharmProjects\brownie\Teems_App_Kid\lib\site-packages\celery\utils\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from collections import Callable ImportError: cannot import name 'Callable' from 'collections' (C:\Users\Codertjay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Comment: I fixed this issue by changing my celery version from 3.* to 5.* and also removed django-celery

Comment: Callable is not in `collections`, do you mean the one from `typing`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Back in 2016 `collections/__init__.py` had an import of `Callable` from [`_collections_abc.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e501a93c18085a0ae0000a759438dcf3c162ddb6/Lib/_collections_abc.py). I guess it was unintentionally added to the celery code.

Comment: @KlausD. Ah. Ok that makes sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The offending line has been removed from Celery [nearly 6 years ago](https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/c21d6a9c17828423fbb1675884b7e5ceeab40167). You should update the celery package to a recent version.

Comment: I never knew they choose best ans

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on **M1 Mac** and **python 3.11**

```
pip install celery==5.2.7
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by changing celery to version 5.2 above and it started working
thanks a lot